# How to mock .then() and .catch() in Jest?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jestjs, mocking, amazon-cognito

can anyone please give me an example of how can I mock .then() block and .catch() block in Jest
I am trying to test AWS cognito.signUp().then().catch()
but returning TypeError: cognito.signUp(...).then(...).catch is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `then` and `catch` in this case are functions related to Promises. So what you probably want to do here is to mock the cognito.signUp function to return a promise.

You can find an example from here: https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-async